# Send content-length in return statement along with download content value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'am trying to fetch the content-length and return it, but not sure how I can return it along with the `Value.Content` property, can someone help me understand how I can return the content-length in a return statement in C#.

```
public Task<Stream> GetCloudBlobStreamAsync(string blobName, string containerName)
{
    var container = GetContainerReference(containerName);
    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    BlobProperties blobProperties = blob.GetProperties();
    long contentLength = blobProperties.ContentLength; // fetching content length

    // Download the blob
    Response<BlobDownloadInfo> download = blob.Download();

    return Task.FromResult(download.Value.Content);
}
```

I want to return content-length along with `download.Value.Content`

Comment: create new class to have 2 properties

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples): Let the return type be `Task<(Stream ContentStream, int ContentLength)>` and return `Task.FromResult((download.Value.Content, contentLength))`.

Comment: As an aside, the method's claim to be asynchronous really isn't the case here. It would b better to use an async method and await anything async.

Comment: Cloud APIs, especially Microsoft's are invariably async. It seems you're using the Azure Blob API, which means `CreateClient` returns a client, not a blob. There's a `GetPropertiesAsync` overload that doesn't block, along with multiple `Download....Async` methods

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with 2 properties one for your content-length and one for your download.Value.Content.Then return the newly created class instead of a Stream

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a `Tuple` to return multiple data.

```
public Task<(Stream, long)> GetCloudBlobStreamAsync(string blobName, string containerName)
{
    var container = GetContainerReference(containerName);
    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    BlobProperties blobProperties = blob.GetProperties();
    long contentLength = blobProperties.ContentLength; // fetching content length

    // Download the blob
    Response<BlobDownloadInfo> download = blob.Download();

    return (Task.FromResult(download.Value.Content), contentLength);
}
```

Tuples can contain multiple values of multiple types, example:

```
(int, long string) values = (3, 12, "Test");
```

You can then access the values:

```
var number = values.Item1; //3
var text = values.Item3; //Test
```

Tuple members can also be named:

```
(int age, string firstName, string lastName) info = (26, "Anna", "Fox");
Console.WriteLine($"{info.firstName} {info.lastName}: {info.age} years old");
```